# Split .csv file based on it size - using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to split a .csv file based on the size. Lets say i have a file called location.csv and the size of the file is 10G . Now when i run a shell script it has to split the file based on the size value provided in the variable 'file_size' , If the value of the file_size variable is 2G then the location.csv file has to be split into 5 files like location_1.csv,location_2.csv,location_3.csv,location_4.csv,location_5.csv.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, start with [How to ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [mcve], thanks

Comment: `split -C 2G location.csv` See [Gnu coreutils `split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned you can use `split` command:
for example something like:

```
split -C $file_size -d location.csv location_
```